# Are AJAX calls to a sub-domain considered Cross Site Scripting?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have Server A (www.example.com) sending information to Server B. I can only have HTML / JS on Server A (and have to do the "crunching" on Server B) so I'm trying to send form data via AJAX (trying to avoid a form post to Server B - don't ask).

Obviously doing an AJAX call cross-domain is considered XSS and a big no-no, but if I were to put Server B in a subdomain (sub.example.com), would that be considered okay?  How are cross-domain errors detected? Does the browser look up DNS records? IP address?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: The Same Origin Policy is mostly to avoid CSRF (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) and helps mitigate the effect of possible XSS attacks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Sub-domains are considered different and will fail the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) unless both sub-domains declare the same `document.domain` DOM property (and even then, different browsers behave differently).

Comment: `document.domain` is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: No. See the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

You can only make an XHR request to the same host, port, and protocol.

If you want to do Ajax without sticking to that, you can look at [JSON-P](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/).

(XSS is a completely different kettle of fish, in which a site allows data to be injected into it (e.g. via a URI) that gets treated as JS allowing third parties to direct people to your site, while they are logged into it, and steal or edit data.)