# Making a post request from a sinatra app to a rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery, sinatra

I need to send a POST request from a sinatra app to a rails app which would return back some json. Im testing this functionality locally. The urls are as follows:

```
Rails app : railsapp.mydomain.com/api/v1.json
Sinatra app: sinatraapp.mydomain.com
```

On localhost, the urls are:

```
Rails app: localhost:3000/api/v1.json
Sinatra app:localhost 3001
```

In my sinatra app running locally, i have the following code to make the POST request locally

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
   $.post("http://localhost:3000/api/v1.json",
     {email:"<email_here>",password:"<password_here>"},
     function(data) {
         //Do something with response
     }
   );

});
```

Also, the `Content-Type` in the request header should be `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. I used REST Client in Firefox to test the request and it works, but in the above code the request is not being made at all. What is the error in my code ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is being stopped as a XSS attack. Even though they are on the same domain, the sub-domains are different, and that's enough. For more information, see [Are AJAX calls to a sub-domain considered Cross Site Scripting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040514/are-ajax-calls-to-a-sub-domain-considered-cross-site-scripting).

To correct this, you could simply make the AJAX hit your local controller, and make the request using ruby, which would not be limited by said restriction.

Answer (score 3):

You can also set this settings:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

This enables you to do cross domain calls with jQuery. It's probably not the best solution, since you are adding a vulnerability by using the following request header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: +1 for the tip, I was unaware of this option in jQuery. Like you said, probably not the best solution, but in some cases, I could see the value...

Comment: @BradWerth thanks! Your solution is obviously a better one. :-)