# Enable cross-domain request wihout using JSONP

Tags: javascript, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Is it possible to enable cross-domain requests with jQuery, without using JSONP?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you can make use of the `script` tag as well.

Comment: Whether those are enabled is mostly a serverside problem? What exactly are you asking for, why do you expect to need jQuery?

Comment: No as far as I know. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: @Gidon: In which environment does your jQuery run, in the browser? Does the targeted server support CORS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, by settings this inside jquery.

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

This enables you to do cross domain calls with jQuery. It's probably not the best solution, since you are adding a vulnerability by using the following request header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
I would recommend to see if JSONP is still an option, this option is preferred.

See this post for more information: [Making a post request from a sinatra app to a rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813249/making-a-post-request-from-a-sinatra-app-to-a-rails-app/12813491#comment17330106_12813491)

Comment: Isn't that automatically set by jQuery?

Comment: @Bergi no, you have to set it manual in some cases. See the official documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

Comment: Only if it is not detected, but usually you don't need to. You will need to set it explicitly if the environment supports cross-domain-requests without CORS

Comment: @Bergi yeah, in his case i think this is the best option so he can assure it's enabled.

Answer (score 0):

yes you should use the header `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *`

then you can use jsonp. the server should respond to with padding that you have giving in your callback .

you can also use the header  `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`(php sccript) on server side

Comment: Huh? CORS is different from JSONP

Comment: yes jsonp is dynamic injection of js

Comment: …and does not need any headers, yes.